# What other languages support Go's style of interfacing without explicit declaration?

Tags: c#, java, interface, d, type-inference

I am a reasonably experiences hobby programmer, and I have good familiarity with C++, D, Java, C# and others.

With the exception of Go, almost every language requires me to explicitly state that I am implementing an interface. This is borderline ridiculous, since we today have compilers for languages like Haskell, which can do almost full-program type inference with very few hints.

What I am looking for is a programming language that does this:

```
interface ITest {
    void Test();
}

class Test {
    void Test() { }
}

void main() {
    ITest x;
    x = new Test;
}
```

What languages would see this, and automatically flag `Test` as implementing `ITest`?

**ETA**: I am not looking for duck typing. I am looking for strictly typed languages with inference.

Comment: Does JavaScript count ? You can call the `Test()` function on any object having it without having to declare an interface.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is fit for SO. If you want to have a list of languages having this fabulous feature of Go, maybe programmers.se would be better.

Comment: Are you looking for any language using duck typing? JS, Python, Ruby, etc?

Comment: see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: @hatchet duck typing is verified dynamically, I'm guessing the OP is interested in statically verified solutions

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289106/are-there-any-static-duck-typed-languages

Answer (score 12, accepted):

D has something called `wrap` in its standard library, Phobos, which can do what you're looking for. Here's an example copied from the function's unittest:

```
interface A {
  int run();
}

interface B {
  int stop();
  @property int status();
}

class X {
  int run() {
    return 1;
  }

  int stop() {
    return 2;
  }

  @property int status() {
    return 3;
  }
}

auto x = new X();

auto ab = x.wrap!(A, B);
A a = ab;
B b = ab;
assert(a.run() == 1);
assert(b.stop() == 2);
assert(b.status == 3);
```

The work will be available starting from v2.064, and it is already on git HEAD.

Comment: This is the link to the pull request https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/pull/1265

Comment: Also if you want your original X back, just `ab.unwrap!X()`.

Answer (score 0):

Virtually any dynamic language out there (javascript, python, etc ...) supports this pattern.  But I'm guessing you are interested in languages which statically verify that the type satisfies the interface in question.

**C++**

This support is not exactly what you are asking for though because you wouldn't use `ITest` directly.  Instead you would use a template which simply access the needed members of the type

```
// C# style solution 
void UseIt(ITest p) { 
  p.Test();
}

// C++ style solution
template <typename T>
void UseIt(T p) { 
  p.Test();
}
```

The C++ `UseIt` method will work for any type which has an accessible member `Test`.  There is no interface needed here

```
class C1 { 
public: 
  void Test() { }
}

class C2 { } 

UseIt<C1>(C1());  // Ok
UseIt<C2>(C2());  // Error!
```

**TypeScript**

Typescript directly implements the pattern you described.  At the end of the day typescript is just a thin wrapper over javascript and hence dynamic.  But it does provide compile time type annotations.  It's support for interfaces exactly matches the pattern you described in the question

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/24/interfaces-walkthrough.aspx

**F#**

F# has similar support to C++ via member constraints on inline declarations

```
let inline UseIt<^T when ^T : (member Test: unit -> unit)> s = ...
```

Comment: Yeah, and D is similar to C++ in this respect.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe i assumed D was but I didn't have enough experience with it to intelligently comment on it

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for: A template/genetic solution has (unless the compiler is VERY smart) several machine code sequences associated, while an interface solution usually has only one (dependent on an interface table lookup).

Comment: @KarlDamgaardAsmussen a C++ template will result in a direct call to the method in question. That should always be less instructions than an interface dispatch.

Comment: But it will create a different function for each type leading to some amount of code bloat.

Comment: @BCS yes that's true. It's different than what Karl was arguing though and I wanted to understand his comment

Comment: @JaredPar: I think Karl was pointing out the code bloat issues: i.e. unless the compiler is smart enough to spot and merge identical template expiations, it will generate several implementations that are each a distinct machine code sequence.